# How to make on logout to redirect into “/app/login”?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

When I make logout on site it is redirected into “/app/login”, as in file app/Providers/Filament/AppPanelProvider.php I have options :

```
class AppPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->default()
            ->plugins([
            ])
            ->id('app')
            ->path('app')
            ->login()
            ->profile()
```

But in some cases “/login” is opened(Say after I refresh full database with migration command and lost current session).

In app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php I changed a line :

```
return route('app/login');
```

But the same result...

If there is a way always to reopen “/app/login” url ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.31.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your AppPanelProvider class:

```
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Navigation\MenuItem;


public function boot(): void
{
    Filament::serving(function () {

        Filament::registerUserMenuItems([
            'logout' => MenuItem::make()->url(route('your-logout-route-name')),
        ]);

    });
}
```

Docs - https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/navigation#customizing-the-logout-link

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Kinger, please provide docs link